# Simple Captcha picture not showing

Tags: php, captcha

I trying to create a simple PHP captcha by following this website:

http://php.detailsinn.com/create-captcha-in-your-php-application/

I do exactly what the tutorial that teach, but in the end the Captcha image are not showing anyway.

I checked in php error log file and using error_reporting to check what is the error, but no error has been show. Here is the script need some help.

**myform.php**

```
<?php session_start(); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    if(isset($_POST['txtName'])){
        $error = '';
        if(isset($_POST['txtCaptcha']) and $_POST['txtCaptcha'] !=''){
            if($_SESSION['captcha_text'] == $_POST['txtCaptcha']){
                // Action of form...
                echo $_POST['txtName'].' is successfully processed';
                exit;
            }else{
                $error = '<font color="red">Sorry Incorrect captcha entered...</font>';
            }
        }else{
            $error = '<font color="red">You have not entered captcha.</font>';
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head><title>Captcha</title></head>
<body>
    <?php if(isset($error)){ echo $error; } ?>
<form action="myform.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="txtName" value="" placeholder="Enter your name" />
    <br /><br />
    <img src="captcha.php" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="txtCaptcha" value="" placeholder="Enter the number you see in the image" />
    <br /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**captcha.php**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // Generate Random Number
    $random_number =  rand(1,9).rand(1,9).rand(1,9);
    $_SESSION['captcha_text'] = $random_number;

    // Insert random number into image
    $captcha_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("captcha.jpg");
    $font_color = imagecolorallocate($captcha_image, 0, 0, 0);
    imagestring($captcha_image, 5, 20, 5, $random_number, $font_color);
    imagejpeg($captcha_image);
    imagedestroy($captcha_image);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we are drawing images on the fly we have to tell the browser about the content we are sending to it, in your case

```
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

it becomes:

```
....
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($captcha_image);
imagedestroy($captcha_image);
```

Also you can verify status

```
/* Attempt to open */
$captcha_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("captcha.jpg");

/* See if it ok */
if($captcha_image)
{

}else{
     // failed to open

    $captcha_image  = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tested the way you listed to verify... It was failed to load the captcha.jpg. But i've no idea why it was failed to load, both of them is at same file

Comment: @JakeCube: Is GD installed ? `var_dump(get_extension_funcs("gd"))`

Comment: I'm sure about the GD was installed or not, i'm using XAMPP 7.0.23. I tested with var_dump it shows 101 unit in array.

Comment: @JakeCube: probably having permission issue, you still can create captcha without using imagecreatefromjpeg, `$captcha_image  = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30);` , here is [tutorial](http://perials.com/tutorial-creating-image-captcha-php-using-gd-library/), see my edit

Comment: Tested with "imagecreatetruecolor", nothing has shown after fail to load image. Going to study the URL you gave brb